# Silent erroer handling in python?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, pandas, error-handling, get-request

I got csv-file with numerous URLs. I read it into a pandas dataframe for convenience. I need to do some statistical work later - and pandas is just handy. It looks a little like this:

```
import pandas as pd
csv = [{"URLs" : "www.mercedes-benz.de", "electric" : 1}, {"URLs" : "www.audi.de", "electric" : 0}, {"URLs" : "ww.audo.e", "electric" : 0}, {"URLs" : "NaN", "electric" : 0}]
df = pd.DataFrame(csv)
```

My task is to check if the websites contain certain strings and to add an extra column with 1 if so, and else 0. For example: I want to check, wether `www.mercedes-benz.de` contains the string `car`. I do the following:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    page_content = requests.get(row['URLs'])
    if "car" in page_content.text:
        df.loc[i, 'car'] = '1'
    else:
        df.loc[i, 'car'] = '0'
```

The problem is: sometimes the URL is wrong/missing. My little script results in a error.

How can I handle/supress the error if the URL is wrong/missing? And, how can I e.g. use `df.loc[i, 'url_wrong'] = '1'` in these cases to indicate that the URL is wrong/missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try defining a function that does the "car" checking first and the use the `.apply` method of a pandas `Series` to get your `1`, `0` or `Wrong URL`. The following should help:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests


data = [{"URLs" : "https://www.mercedes-benz.de", "electric" : 1},
        {"URLs" : "https://www.audi.de", "electric" : 0}, 
        {"URLs" : "https://ww.audo.e", "electric" : 0}, 
        {"URLs" : "NaN", "electric" : 0}]


def contains_car(link):
    try:
        return int('car' in requests.get(link).text)
    except:
        return "Wrong/Missing URL"


df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['extra_column'] = df.URLs.apply(contains_car)


#                           URLs  electric extra_column
# 0  https://www.mercedes-benz.de         1            1
# 1           https://www.audi.de         0            1
# 2             https://ww.audo.e         0    Wrong/Missing URL
# 3                           NaN         0    Wrong/Missing URL
```

#### Edit:

You can search for more than just one keyword in the returned text from your HTTP request. Depending on the condition you set up, this can be done with either the builtin function `any` or the builtin function `all`. Using `any` means that finding any of the keywords should return 1, while using `all` means that all the keywords have to be matched in order to return 1. In the following example, I am using `any` with keywords such as 'car', 'automobile', 'vehicle':

```
import pandas as pd
import requests


data = [{"URLs" : "https://www.mercedes-benz.de", "electric" : 1},
        {"URLs" : "https://www.audi.de", "electric" : 0}, 
        {"URLs" : "https://ww.audo.e", "electric" : 0}, 
        {"URLs" : "NaN", "electric" : 0}]


def contains_keywords(link, keywords):
    try:
        output = requests.get(link).text
        return int(any(x in output for x in keywords))
    except:
        return "Wrong/Missing URL"


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
mykeywords = ('car', 'vehicle', 'automobile')
df['extra_column'] = df.URLs.apply(lambda l: contains_keywords(l, mykeywords))
```

Should yield:

```
#                            URLs  electric       extra_column
# 0  https://www.mercedes-benz.de         1                  1
# 1           https://www.audi.de         0                  1
# 2             https://ww.audo.e         0  Wrong/Missing URL
# 3                           NaN         0  Wrong/Missing URL
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @abdou is it possibe to search for several key-words using a `or` operator? I tried numerous ways and couldn't make it happen. I could open up a new question, but I thought I ask here first..

Comment: This is perfect. If I could, I'd give you another "question" answered!

Comment: @Rachel, I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I do get you right, that `'NaN'` is a "wrong/missing" URL. In this case you can just check for that. There are endless ways to indicate a missing URL. I'd prefere a missing value for `car`: Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
csv = [{"URLs" : "www.mercedes-benz.de", "electric" : 1}, {"URLs" : "www.audi.de", "electric" : 0}, {"URLs" : "ww.audo-car.e", "electric" : 0}, {"URLs" : "NaN", "electric" : 0}]
df = pd.DataFrame(csv)

print(df)

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    page_content = row['URLs']
    if page_content is None or page_content is "NaN":
        df.loc[i, 'car'] = None
    elif "car" in page_content:
        df.loc[i, 'car'] = True
    else:
        df.loc[i, 'car'] = False 
    print(df.loc[i, 'car'])

print(df)
```

I edited some more things in your code, as they did not work. E.g this line with `page_content = requests.get(row['URLs'])` - `requests` is not defined. I guess you mean `row`.

Comment: Thanky you! This is great help!