# Search for keywords in text and create a data frame column per found keyword?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping

I am searching through some webpages for keywords. Thanks again @Abdou for helping me out with the [silent error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44590079/silent-erroer-handling-in-python)! I'll give you an example:

```
# this is basically what I do
import pandas as pd
import requests


data = [{"URLs" : "https://www.mercedes-benz.de", "electric" : 1},
        {"URLs" : "https://www.audi.de", "electric" : 0}, 
        {"URLs" : "https://ww.audo.de", "electric" : 0}, 
        {"URLs" : "NaN", "electric" : 0}]


def contains_keywords(link, keywords):
    try:
        output = requests.get(link).text
        return int(any(x in output for x in keywords))
    except:
        return "Wrong/Missing URL"


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
mykeywords = ('car', 'vehicle', 'automobile')
df['extra_column'] = df.URLs.apply(lambda l: contains_keywords(l, mykeywords))
```

As you can see, I request the URLs stored in `df.data` and search for keywords from `mykeywords` and store the binary result in `extra_column`. The script basically yields the following:

```
#                            URLs  electric       extra_column
# 0  https://www.mercedes-benz.de         1                  1
# 1           https://www.audi.de         0                  1
# 2             https://ww.audo.e         0                  0
# 3                           NaN         0  Wrong/Missing URL
```

So far, I only know, if I find a keyword. But I would like to find out, which keywords I find - without running `contains_keywords()` for each keyword in `mykeywords` individually. Is there a way to create a new column per each keyword and store the result (`1` = keyword found) in a the `DataFrame`? That is: I need additional columns in `df` for each keyword.

Comment: "I would like to find out, which keywords I find..." means you need additional columns in `df` for _each_ keyword?

Comment: Hi Dmitriy, exactly that's what I want!  A column for each keyword. Is that possible? I tried everything I know, but I did not work out so far. Sorry that my question isn't clear. I will edit it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import requests


data = [{"URLs" : "https://www.mercedes-benz.de", "electric" : 1},
        {"URLs" : "https://www.audi.de", "electric" : 0}, 
        {"URLs" : "https://ww.audo.de", "electric" : 0}, 
        {"URLs" : "NaN", "electric" : 0}]


def contains_keywords(link, keyword):
    try:
        output = requests.get(link).text
        return int(keyword in output)
    except:
        return "Wrong/Missing URL"


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
mykeywords = ('car', 'vehicle', 'automobile')
for keyword in mykeywords:
    df[keyword] = df.URLs.apply(lambda l: contains_keywords(l, keyword))
```

Comment: Wow! This is super cool! I just don't understand how just yet. It semms that you can call `keyword` as a `df.column` directly? Super cool! Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Dmitriy Fialkovskiy, just one last quick question: I understand that given the `forloop`, I apply the `containains_keywords` function for each `keyword` in `mykeywords`. So in this case, 3 times. Does that also mean, that it takes 3 times as long as searching `int(any(x in output for x in keywords))`  in one go?

Comment: hi Rachel, in my version of code there's no `any` function, it only checks one keyword at a time.

Comment: Hi, yes and that is the need thing! But in my original question, I used an `any` function. Let me put it this way: If I have `2` keywords in `mykeywords` does it take twice as long when compared to having `1` keyword in `mykeywords`?

Comment: that's a very deep question, I don't know actually. But you can make an experiment with a big list of keywords and manually measure execution time in both cases=)